# launch an installed native android app from a link in a web app

Tags: android, web-applications, intel-xdk

I am attempting to build my first web-app for android phones using Intel XDK.

I have been able to successfully open the dialer through a link (tel:) and an external web page through a link (`<a href="#" onclick="openInAppBrowserBlank('http://williamsislandclub.com?userId=1');"><img src="img/wi_app_button_essentials_blue.png"></a>`).

**QUESTION:** There is a **native Android app** installed on most of our community's phones (**com.app.gateaccess**).  I want to create a link that opens this app and cannot find a solution that I can comprehend.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add an intent filter with custom scheme into the manifist file, in respective Activity tag of your app. Format is: `<scheme>://<host>:<port>/<path>`

**Example:**

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:scheme="<PUT SCHEME HERE>" android:host="<PUT URL HERE>" android:path="<PUT PATH HERE>"/>
  </intent-filter>
```

replace this tag with url scheme like http or https

replace this tag with your url. (i.e mycoolapps.com)

replace this tag with path after url i.e (/sweetApp).

**Complete Example:**

Let say if you want to open app with following url:

http://mycoolapps.com/sweetApp

Your intent filter would look like the following:

```
 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="mycoolapps.com" android:path="/sweetApp"/>
      </intent-filter>
```

Comment: sorry for my inexperience - may I impose for a little clarification? (1) The Intel XDK does not create a manifest file named as such; where would I insert the intent? (2) the URL is also throwing me off - if the native app is installed on my Android phone, what is the url scheme, the url, and path I would use? in the Google Marketplace, the app package name is com.app.gateaccess

Comment: Sorry, I don't work with intel-xdk. My given solution is generic for android native apps. These lines are need to be added in manifist file of native android app.